# AWS EMR Multiple Jobs Dependency Contention

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-kinesis

### Problem

I am attempting to run 2 pyspark steps in EMR both reading from Kinesis using  KinesisUtils.  This requires dependent library, spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11.

I'm using Terraform to stand up the EMR cluster and invoke the steps both with args:

*--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.4.5*

There appears to be contention on start up with both steps downloading the jar from maven and causing a checksum failure.

### Things attempted

1. I've tried to move the download of the jar to the bootstrap bash script using:

sudo spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.4.5

This causes problems as spark-shell is only available on the master node and bootstrap tries to run on all nodes.

2. I've tried to limit the above to only run on master using

grep-q'"isMaster":true'/mnt/var/lib/info/instance.json ||{echo "Not running on masternode,nothing further to do" && exit 0;}

That didn't seem to work.

3. I've attempted to add spark configuration to do this in EMR configuration.json

   {

   "Classification": "spark-defaults",

   "Properties": {

   ```
   "spark.jars.packages": "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.4.5"
   ```

   }

   }

This also didn't work and seemed to stop all jars being copied to the master node dir

/home/hadoop/.ivy2/cache

What does work manually is logging onto the master node and running

sudo spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.4.5

Then submitting the jobs manually without the --packages option.

Currently, all I need to do is manually start the failed jobs separately (clone steps in AWS console) and everything runs fine.

I just want to be able to start the cluster with all steps successfully starting, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the required jars and upload them to s3.(One time)
2. While running your pyspark jobs from  step, pass `--jars <s3 location of jar>` in your spark-submit

Comment: Thanks really appreciate you looking, this is what I ended up doing and it's working now, just seems a bit of a workaround.